# MaterialUI Dropdown Icon does not expand menu

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use the MaterialUI Select component ([Reference Doc](https://material-ui.com/api/select/)) with the IconComponent option.

The icon shows up, but when you click it the menu does not expand.

**Here is an example in codesandbox**:
[Material Select Icon Issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-select-icon-issue-7y9dg)

*How can I have the menu expand normally? Did I format the icon incorrectly?*

Answer (score 2):

Pass `.MuiSvgIcon-root` and `.MuiSelect-icon` classes as props to `CheckMark` component in your `CheckMarkInternal()` method.

```
const CheckMarkInternal = () => {
    return (
      <CheckMark
        fill="purple"
        width={50}
        height={50}
        className="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSelect-icon"
        style={{ pointerEvents: "none", marginLeft: "20", marginRight: "20" }}
      />
    );
};
```

Check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-select-icon-issue-ntlsr) please.